# difference between javascript array and jquery set

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm relatively new to javascript and very new to jquery.

I have noticed that the jquery set returned by `jQuery()` selector shares a lot of similarities with javascript array e.g. elements in the jquery set can be accessed by the square bracket `[]` syntax

So I was wondering, is there any foundamental difference between jquery set and javascript array? Or they can be thought of as two ways of representing the same thing?

Comment: The jquery "set" is an array-like object, so though it's not an array you can use array methods with it via `.call()` and `.apply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the person who was responsible for this jQuery feature, I thought I would share some historical notes.

If you study the jQuery API, you may notice something odd: the object returned by `$()`/`jQuery()` is not only an "array-like" object with a `.length` property and `[i]` access to its elements, but it *also* has a couple of fairly redundant methods: `.get(i)` and `.size()`.

`.get(i)` is very similar to an array's `[i]`: it returns one of the elements of the jQuery array/object. And `.size()` is the same as `.length`.

In fact, if you look at the implementation of `.size()` you will see that it simply returns the `.length` property:

```
// The number of elements contained in the matched element set
size: function() {
    return this.length;
},
```

There is a little more to `.get()`. If you don't pass an argument, it is the same as `.toArray()`, and if you do pass an argument it allows both positive and negative indexes. Negative indexes count backwards from the end of the array similar to Python or Ruby.

But for the simple case of a non-negative index, `.get(i)` boils down to:

```
// Get the Nth element in the matched element set
get: function( num ) {
    return this[ num ];
},
```

Why all this redundancy? `.size()` and `.get(i)` just do the same thing as the usual `.length` or `[i]`, so why have both?

In the very first jQuery release in January 2006 (long before 1.0), the object returned by `$()` was *not* an "array-like" object. It was just a JavaScript object with `.get(i)` and `.size()` methods. The actual list of DOM elements was a separate "private" property of the jQuery object, and you were supposed to use those methods to access its elements and length.

As I worked with that initial jQuery release, it seemed a bit clumsy to have to call `.get(i)` and `.size()` to access the elements of the returned jQuery object. This object seemed to be a lot like an array, but you couldn't access its elements the same way as a normal array. So I thought, why not make it act more like a real array with `[i]` and `.length`?

It was a fairly simple change to do that, so we ran with it, but we kept the old `.get(i)` and `size()` methods for compatibility with code that already used those.

Now a confession: I don't remember the reason for making the return object an array-like object instead of directly inheriting from `Array`. (It was 11 years ago after all!)

We would have preferred making this object an actual array, but there was a good reason why that would work. Perhaps I will remember after sleeping on it, but in the meantime, this is how we got to the place where the jQuery return object is "array-like" but not a true array.

Answer (score 3):

From their own docs ([found here](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)):

> The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array; it has a length
>   property and the elements in the object can be accessed by their
>   numeric indices [0] to [length-1]. Note that a jQuery object is not
>   actually a Javascript Array object, so it does not have all the
>   methods of a true Array object such as join().

So a jquery object is sort of *array like*, but it's not an array. Basically, an array will have methods the jquery object lacks, and the jquery object has methods that arrays lack. I would generally try not to treat the jquery objects as arrays, and instead try to use a jquery method whenever tempted to use an array method (ie, use `.each` instead of the array method `.forEach`).

EDIT:

After reading more about the jquery objects, they do share a lot of methods with arrays, such as `.find`. Moreover, it also provides a `.toArray` method which can be used to convert the jquery object into an *actual* javascript array.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery object is a wrapper around an array of DOM elements. So a "jQuery array" is a jQuery object.

Comment: But does jQuery use an actual array under the covers, or an array-like object?

Comment: @Node.JS - That doesn't prove anything either way about how a jQuery object works, that's just a way of getting the elements as an array. Actually, given it is [implemented as `return slice.call(this)`](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.toArray) that implies that there isn't already an actual array available.